# Handling dialog windows on a locked machine

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, autoit

We are using Selenium WebDriver to automate web applications in multiple browsers and AutoIt to handle window objects. We are working in a VM.

I click the save button in the Filedownload dialog window using AutoIt, but AutoIt doesn't perform clicks when the system is locked. `ControlClick()` and `ControlSend()` instead of `ControlClick()` and `Send()` work for Google Chrome when the system is locked, but not for Internet Explorer.

I tried `WinActivate()`, `WinExists()`, `ControlClick()`, `ControlFocus()` and `ControlSend()`. Here is the code:

```
_AutoIt.ControlClick("File Download", "Do you want to open or save this file?", "[ID:4427; TEXT:&Save; CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:2]");
```

Answer (score -1):

In order for Autoit to find child windows, you need to enable it

```
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
```

Comment: Hi Milos, i need to identify and work on a windows pop up from a web application. I have a script that runs on both IE and Chrome. That script works on Chrome when is system is locked and if not locked. But in IE, the same scripts runs fine when the system is not locked. The issue is only when the system is locked on IE.